# URL key for specified store already exists in category in Magento 2.1.1

Tags: magento-2.1

I am receiving the following error:

`URL key for specified store already exists in category`

How to fix this error when i want to update my Magento version 2.1.1 category.This error not update it.Anyone has good suggestion for it?

Comment: Please don't just dump error messages in the question form. You should at least explain when it happens and if you did any changes before. To debug errors, follow this guide: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: I have already written it.when i updated my category,then this error occur.Please read question carefully @SR_Magento .

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. I hope it gonna help You.

It happens when You try create similar categories in other root category.
It happens because firs category won't be include in url rewrites. Eg:

`First Default Category -> Test1 -> Test2`
create paths:
`/test1.html` and `/test1/test2.html`

When You try to create :

`Second Default Category -> Test1 -> Test2`
Magento will create rewrite with paths:
`/test1.html` and `/test1/test2.html` also.

Try to set different url category or use one root category.